# Why does revalidatePath trigger a refetch when it specifically states that it will not?

Tags: next.js, app-router

You can put `revalidatePath` in a server action and whenever you run the action, it will refetch the data on the route you're on. This despite the docs stating that it will not:

> revalidatePath only invalidates the cache when the included path is
> next visited. This means calling revalidatePath with a dynamic route
> segment will not immediately trigger many revalidations at once. The
> invalidation only happens when the path is next visited.

This behavior is great, honestly, it's just ironic that one of the only good things in Nextjs right now is an unintended behavior. Or am I missing something?

Answer (score 4):

You would normally have this workflow in your Next.js application:

```
[Client] ---> [Server Action] ---> [revalidatePath] ---> [Cache Invalidation] ---> [Next Visit Triggers Refetch]
```

When you call [`revalidatePath`](https://nextjs.org/docs/app/api-reference/functions/revalidatePath), it marks the [cache](https://nextjs.org/docs/app/building-your-application/caching#data-cache) for the specified path as invalid. That means the cached data for this path is flagged as outdated and needs to be updated upon the next visit.
The actual refetching of data, as per the documentation, is supposed to occur only when the invalidated path is visited again. It does not pre-fetch or immediately refetch the data after invalidation.

But a [server action](https://nextjs.org/docs/app/building-your-application/data-fetching/server-actions-and-mutations) is an *asynchronous* function executed on the server.

When a server action is invoked, and it includes a call to `revalidatePath`, it is possible that the act of navigating to or refreshing the page (which implicitly involves visiting the path) triggers the [revalidation and refetching process](https://nextjs.org/docs/app/building-your-application/data-fetching/fetching-caching-and-revalidating#fetching-data-on-the-server-with-fetch) as a direct consequence of the server action's execution.

If the server action modifies data that affects the output of the page, Next.js might automatically ensure that the data is fresh on the next render, which could be perceived as an immediate refetch.

---

> Do we still need to call `revalidatePath` for a server component after updating some data it needs to fetch on re-render if it is [annotated with `noStore`](https://nextjs.org/docs/app/api-reference/functions/unstable_noStore), which disables any caching?

True: if a server component uses `unstable_noStore` to opt out of caching, the typical need for calling [`revalidatePath`](https://nextjs.org/docs/app/api-reference/functions/revalidatePath) after data updates might seem redundant at first glance.

`unstable_noStore` is designed to make sure the component's data is fetched fresh on each render, effectively bypassing the Next.js caching mechanism for that component. That means that any data fetched within this component will not be cached, thus making sure that the latest data is always retrieved directly from the source (e.g., a database or API).

However, the role of `revalidatePath` extends *beyond* just controlling the cache behavior of individual components. It is used to invalidate the cache for a specific path globally, making sure that all data associated with that path is refreshed upon the next visit, across all components and pages that might be involved. That is particularly relevant in scenarios where data updates affect multiple components or pages, not just those explicitly marked with `unstable_noStore`.

So, if your server component with `unstable_noStore` is the *only consumer* of the updated data, and you are certain that no other parts of your application need to be refreshed as a result of the update, *then* calling `revalidatePath` may not be necessary.
However, if the update has broader implications for your application, affecting other components or pages that might cache their data, invoking `revalidatePath` is still a valuable step to make sure consistency and freshness across your application.

Comment: Hello VonC, do we still need to call `revalidatePath` for a server component after updating some data it needs to fetch on re-render if it is annotated with `noStore`, which disables any caching? https://nextjs.org/docs/app/api-reference/functions/unstable_noStore